# Java 8 - External Iteration performing better than Internal Iteration?

Tags: java, iterator, java-8, java-stream

So I was reading a book for Java 8, when I saw them doing comparison between external and internal iteration and thought about comparing the two, performance wise.

I have a method that just sums up a sequence of integers up to `n`.

Iterative one:

```
private static long iterativeSum(long n) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long sum = 0;

    for(long i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        sum+=i;
    }


    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Iterative Sum Duration: " + (endTime-startTime)/1000000);

    return sum;
}
```

Sequential One - using internal iteration

```
private static long sequentialSum(long n) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    //long sum = LongStream.rangeClosed(1L, n)
    long sum = Stream.iterate(1L, i -> i+1)
            .limit(n)
            .reduce(0L, (i,j) -> i+j);

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Sequential Sum Duration: " + (endTime-startTime)/1000000);

    return sum;
}
```

I tried to do some benchmarking on them, it turns out that the one using external iteration performs far better than the one using internal iteration.

Here's my driver code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long n = 100000000L;

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    iterativeSum(n);
    sequentialSum(n);
    }
    iterativeSum(n);
    sequentialSum(n);
}
```

The running time for the Iteravtive one was always < 50ms whereas the execution time for Sequential one was always > 250ms.

I am not able to understand why internal iteration is not out performing external iteration here?

Comment: fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java your test doesn't do what you expect it to do

Comment: I tried running these methods in a loop for more than some thousand time to warm up the JIT and traverse all code paths. But not once I saw the gap reducing between the 2. Iterative is always <50 and Sequential (internal iteration) is always >250ms

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though the presented results are completely irrelevant, the observed effect actually takes place: the Stream API do has an overhead which for such simple tasks cannot be totally eliminated in real applications even after warm-up. Let's write a [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class IterativeSum {
    @Param({ "100", "10000", "1000000" })
    private int n;

    public static long iterativeSum(long n) {
        long sum = 0;

        for(long i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long is() {
        return iterativeSum(n);
    }
}
```

Here's baseline test: plain loop. The results on my box are the following:

```
Benchmark             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
IterativeSum.is       100  avgt   30     0.074 ±   0.001  us/op
IterativeSum.is     10000  avgt   30     6.361 ±   0.009  us/op
IterativeSum.is   1000000  avgt   30   688.527 ±   0.910  us/op
```

Here's your version of Stream API based iteration:

```
public static long sequentialSumBoxed(long n) {
    return Stream.iterate(1L, i -> i+1).limit(n)
                 .reduce(0L, (i,j) -> i+j);
}

@Benchmark
public long ssb() {
    return sequentialSumBoxed(n);
}
```

The results look like this:

```
Benchmark             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
IterativeSum.ssb      100  avgt   30     1.253 ±   0.084  us/op
IterativeSum.ssb    10000  avgt   30   134.959 ±   0.421  us/op
IterativeSum.ssb  1000000  avgt   30  9119.422 ±  22.817  us/op
```

Very disappointing: 13-21x slower. This version has many boxing operations inside, that's why primitive stream specializations were created. Let's check non-boxed version:

```
public static long sequentialSum(long n) {
    return LongStream.iterate(1L, i -> i+1).limit(n)
                     .reduce(0L, (i,j) -> i+j);
}

@Benchmark
public long ss() {
    return sequentialSum(n);
}
```

The results are the following:

```
Benchmark             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
IterativeSum.ss       100  avgt   30     0.661 ±   0.001  us/op
IterativeSum.ss     10000  avgt   30    67.498 ±   5.732  us/op
IterativeSum.ss   1000000  avgt   30  1982.687 ±  38.501  us/op
```

Much better now, but still 2.8-10x times slower. An alternative would be to use the range:

```
public static long rangeSum(long n) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n).sum();
}

@Benchmark
public long rs() {
    return rangeSum(n);
}
```

The results are the following:

```
Benchmark             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
IterativeSum.rs       100  avgt   30     0.316 ±   0.001  us/op
IterativeSum.rs     10000  avgt   30    28.646 ±   0.065  us/op
IterativeSum.rs   1000000  avgt   30  2158.962 ± 514.780  us/op
```

Now it's 3.1-4.5x times slower. The cause of this slowness is that Stream API has very long call chain which hits the `MaxInlineLevel` JVM limit, so it cannot be fully inlined by default. You may increase this limit setting like `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=20` and get the following result:

```
Benchmark             (n)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
IterativeSum.rs       100  avgt   30     0.111 ±   0.001  us/op
IterativeSum.rs     10000  avgt   30     9.552 ±   0.017  us/op
IterativeSum.rs   1000000  avgt   30   729.935 ±  31.915  us/op
```

Much better: now it's only 1.05-1.5x slower.

The problem with this test is that the loop body of iterative version is very simple, thus could be efficiently unrolled and vectorized by JIT-compiler, and it's much harder to do this with the same efficiency for sophisticated Stream API code. However in real applications you're unlikely to sum consequtive numbers in a loop (why not write `n*(n+1)/2` instead?). With real problems Stream API overhead is much lower even with default `MaxInlineLevel` setting.

Comment: Seems interesting, I'll look more into the MaxInlineLevel do some more testing and then accept your answer. Thanks.